# How can I move a file to another directory using Vala?

Tags: file, directory, move, glib, vala

I am trying to move a file to another directory according to the [Vala documentation](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.move.html) but the following method is not working.

Please tell me if I misunderstand how the move method works.

#### moveMyFile V1:

```
public void moveMyFile(){

    GLib.File dest = GLib.File.new_for_path("~/Desktop/dest/");
    GLib.File src = GLib.File.new_for_path("~/Desktop/src/test.txt");

    print("\ndest path : %s \n", dest.get_path());
    print("src path : %s \n", src.get_path());

    if(dest.query_exists() && src.query_exists()){
        try {
            src.move(dest, FileCopyFlags.NONE, null);
        } catch (Error e) {
            print ("moveMyFile Error: %s\n", e.message);
        }
    }

}
```

Terminal output (no error, no test.txt in dest):

```
dest path : /home/srdr/Serdar/Workspaces/WorkspaceBudgie/budgie-projects/budgie-trash/build/~/Desktop/dest 
src path : /home/srdr/Serdar/Workspaces/WorkspaceBudgie/budgie-projects/budgie-trash/build/~/Desktop/src/test.txt
```

#### ------------------Update 1----------------------

#### moveMyFile V2:

```
public void moveMyFile(){

    GLib.File dest = GLib.File.new_for_path("~/Desktop/dest/test.txt");
    GLib.File src = GLib.File.new_for_path("~/Desktop/src/test.txt");

    print("\ndest path : %s \n", dest.get_path());
    print("src path : %s \n", src.get_path());

    if(dest.query_exists() && src.query_exists()){
        try {
            src.move(dest, FileCopyFlags.NONE, null);
        } catch (Error e) {
            print ("moveMyFile Error: %s\n", e.message);
        }
    }

}
```

Terminal output (no error, no test.txt in dest):

```
dest path : /home/srdr/Serdar/Workspaces/WorkspaceBudgie/budgie-projects/budgie-trash/build/~/Desktop/dest/test.txt 
src path : /home/srdr/Serdar/Workspaces/WorkspaceBudgie/budgie-projects/budgie-trash/build/~/Desktop/src/test.txt
```

#### ------------------Update 2----------------------

#### moveMyFile V3:

public void moveMyFile(){

```
string homePath = Environment.get_home_dir();
string destPath = homePath + "/Desktop/dest/test.txt";
string srcPath = homePath + "/Desktop/src/test.txt";

GLib.File dest = GLib.File.new_for_path(destPath);
GLib.File src = GLib.File.new_for_path(srcPath);

print("\ndest path : %s \n", dest.get_path());
print("src path : %s \n", src.get_path());

if(dest.query_exists() && src.query_exists()){
    try {
        src.move(dest, FileCopyFlags.NONE, null);
    } catch (Error e) {
        print ("moveMyFile Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
}
```

}

Terminal output (no error, no test.txt in dest):

```
dest path : /home/srdr/Desktop/dest/test.txt 
src path : /home/srdr/Desktop/src/test.txt
```

Comment: You have to specify a file name as the destination, I directory name won't do.

Comment: Also: What is the error message you are seeing? "Does not work" is usually too vague for us to help you.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff ok i updated as you say. no error, no test.txt in dest. Still not working. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I fixed the homePath in Update 2 but the problem continues.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I was checking the dest file exists. I removed dest.query_exists() from the if statement. Now it is working.

Comment: Of course ... I don't know why I didn't catch this earlier. Good thing you figured it out :)

Comment: Thank you : ) @JensMühlenhoff

Answer (score 2):

I was checking the dest file exists. I removed dest.query_exists()  from the if statement. Now it is working.

```
 public void moveMyFile(){

        string homePath = Environment.get_home_dir();
        string destPath = homePath + "/Desktop/dest/test.txt";
        string srcPath = homePath + "/Desktop/src/test.txt";

        GLib.File dest = GLib.File.new_for_path(destPath);
        GLib.File src = GLib.File.new_for_path(srcPath);

        print("\ndest path : %s \n", dest.get_path());
        print("src path : %s \n", src.get_path());

        if(src.query_exists()){
            try {
                print ("moveMyFile try\n");
                src.move(dest, FileCopyFlags.NONE, null);
            } catch (Error e) {
                print ("moveMyFile Error: %s\n", e.message);
            }
        }

    }
```